# adapter-deployer SEVERE: Missing xml file or Not Found error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Getting the below error while deploying the .wlapp using Ant scripts:

> [adapter-deployer] SEVERE: Missing xml file

The Ant task:

```
adapter-deployer worklightServerHost="hostname:10039/Demo" deployable="C:\DemoApp-all.wlapp"
```

Note:

- The Worklight WAR file is deployed and I can access the console url by using hostname:10039/Demo/console.
- Also in the ant script if I use worklightServerHost url as hostname:10039/ (I have ensured the port/host number exists in Virtual Hosts > default_host > Host Aliases) I get the below error:

> [adapter-deployer] SEVERE: Not Found;
>
> ## SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to
>   handle /console/api/adapters/upload has not been defined.
>
> #### SRVE0255E:
>   A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle hostname:10039 has not been define
>   d.
>
> *IBM WebSphere Application Server*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to deploy the adapter, yet you point to the application (.wlapp).
You should point the ant script to the .adapter file of your project instead.

Comment: oops...sorry for that. I corrected it and it worked with hostname:10039/context-name. So context-name is a must. Thanks

Comment: One additional question. Is there a ANT task to remove the .wlapp file ?